# How remove Duplicates In While Loop if you read each words

Tags: php, html, mysqli

How can I remove duplicates in this snippet. Distinct function in the query will not work due you reading each word every loop and add into the table. How can i show all distinct data to show in my table

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbProject");
    $output = '';
    if(isset($_POST["query"]))
    {
        $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
        $SearchEach= explode(" ",$search);
        $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Book ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Author</th>
                                <th>Tags</th>
                                <th>Status</th>

                            </tr>';
        foreach($SearchEach as $value){
            $query = "
                SELECT * FROM tblProject 
                WHERE tyear >=YEAR(NOW())-30 AND (tags LIKE '%".$value."%'OR
                     tcname LIKE '%".$value."%' OR
                     author LIKE '%".$value."%' OR
                     status LIKE '%".$value."%')";
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $output .= '<tr>
                                <td>'.$row["tcno"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["tcname"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["Author"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["tags"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>
                            </tr>';
                    }
            }
            echo $output;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What field do you want to be distinct ? Your query response returns multiple fields.

Comment: Hello Mr Harris. I making advance query that  if a search a project from my database it will look for a word related for that project.  My idea in this project is inserting all data into a table reQuery it with a distinct function but it is redundant. Do you have any other solution  for this?

Comment: push the results to a different array first then use array_unique. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: delboy1978uk .Hello what is the right way using parameters?

Comment: `array_push(<new stack>, <values>)` `$stack = array_unique($stack);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `tcno` field values are unique you can use the following logic to NOT SHOW already shown records

```
$processedRecrods = [];

foreach ($SearchEach as $value) {
    $query = "
        SELECT * FROM tblProject 
        WHERE tyear >=YEAR(NOW())-30 AND (tags LIKE '%" . $value . "%'OR
        tcname LIKE '%" . $value . "%' OR
        author LIKE '%" . $value . "%' OR
        status LIKE '%" . $value . "%')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    //See if record with this tcno is already processed / displayed in table
    if (!in_array($row['tcno'], $processedRecrods)) {
            $output .= '<tr>
                            <td>' . $row["tcno"] . '</td>
                            <td>' . $row["tcname"] . '</td>
                            <td>' . $row["Author"] . '</td>
                            <td>' . $row["tags"] . '</td>
                            <td>' . $row["status"] . '</td>
                        </tr>';

            //Add tcno in the array of processed records
            $processedRecrods[] = $row["tcno"];
        }
    }
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: Perfect it works. Thanks for the code. Its a big help. Thank you so much you so great.

Answer (score 1):

First store only the IDs of the rows found during the various searches. Then, remove duplicate IDs. Thereafter, per unique ID, retrieve and display the relevant rows.

Comment: Gert-Jan i thinking that one but i dont know how can i materialize it. I am newbie in Php. if you can show me some code it would be a big help. My last idea is inserting all data in a temp table  and use Distinct function in the query but that idea is redundant  and it will make the database slow

Answer (score 1):

I would push the results to a new stack and use `array_unique`.

```
<?php
$newStack = [];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($newStack, $row);
}

$newStack = array_unique($newStack);

foreach($newStack as $row) {
    $output .= "my html";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. For this code. I  think this is the code  in my problem

Comment: $output .='
   <td>'.$row [0].'<td>
   <td>'.$row [1].'<td>
   <td>'.$row [2].'<td>
   <td>'.$row [3].'<td>
   <td>'.$row [4].'<td>
 ';
 Is this correct when fetching the array

Comment: That should be correct since you're just passing in the whole row & it holds it's structure. If you're unsure of what to reference `var_dump()` the `$newStack`